# SMT32 How do you make the LED toggle when the button is pressed and simultaneously with another button?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, stm32, nucleo

```c
    //setup
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN; //enable the bus for port IOPA.

    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x400; // MODER5 (PA5) LD2,
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x100000; // MODER10 (PA10) LED

    GPIOC->PUPDR |= 0x2000000; // (PC13) B1
    GPIOA->PUPDR |= 0x20; //(PA2) B2

    //main
  while (1)
  {
      if(GPIOA->IDR |= 0x4){
          GPIOA->BSRR = 0x400;
          HAL_Delay(1000);
          GPIOA->BRR = 0x400;
          HAL_Delay(1000);
      }

      if(GPIOC->IDR &= 0x2000){
      GPIOA->BRR = 0x20;
      }
      else{
      GPIOA->BSRR = 0x20;
      }
  }
```

So the first if statement, the led is toggling on its own and the button is not working.
the second if statement is correct but it needs to work like simultaneously like `millis()` in Arduino IDE.

My questions are, is there anything I missed with configuring the button and how to make it work simultaneously?

Comment: "the button is pressed and simultaneously with another button" is _very unlikely_. Code samples input far faster than human fingers trying to coordinate mechanical operated devices.  Instead consider the onset of button presses are _nearly_ the same time, but one button likely beats the other.

Comment: `if( GPIOA->IDR |= 0x4 )` will always be true. I don't think you understand C syntax for boolean and assignment operations...

Comment: similarly `if(GPIOC->IDR &= 0x2000)` is probably not what you intend.

Comment: how can i make it when it reads something with bit manipulation?

Comment: Why worry about bit manipulation? If you have two buttons and you want to toggle the LED when both are pressed, then you have each button on it's own GPIO and then it's a simple `if (gpioA && gpioB) { /* toggle the LED */ }`. Keep it simple. You could even put both buttons in a series and use a single GPIO if you wanted. You would simply press both to trigger the interrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made some very basic errors with C operators.

```
if(GPIOA->IDR |= 0x4)
```

means the same as:

```
temporary_value = (GPIOA->IDR | 0x4);

GPIOA->IDR = temporary_value;

if (temporary_value != 0)
```

This is wrong for two reasons:  firstly, you aren't allowed to write to IDR, it is the *input data register*.  Secondly the `if` control expression will always be true because anything OR 4 is always not equal to zero.

Similarly further down `&=` is also an assignment operator, you are trying to write to the input register again.

To test if a bit in a register is set, use:

```
if ((GPIOA->IDR & (1 << n)) != 0)
```

Where `n` is the bit number you want to test.  Don't calculate the bitmask in your head (eg: `0x400`) because you are more likely to make an error.